# Spacing after definition

Tags: macros

I have the following definition in my latex document:

```
\newcommand{\emp}{\texttt{EMP}}
```

This eats the space after it. For example, if I type

```
Assume that relation \emp is fragmented
```

The latex output is

```
 Assume that EMPis fragmented (notice the lack of space after EMP).
```

If I change the definition to put space after EMP like this:

```
\newcommand{\emp}{\texttt{EMP} }
```

The above example works, but then I have weird spaces before punctuations that follow `\emp` (e.g., in `\emp,` I have an extra space before `,`).

Is there a proper way of defining these so I won't have this problem?

Comment: Use `\emp{} is` or `\emp\ is`.

Comment: Thanks; I need the second version since I am not looking at emphasis. The version generally works but when I have a punctuation afterwards I need to be careful. For example, I need \emp,\ since \emp\, eats up the , -- is this expected?

Comment: I didn't understand your comment about emphasis. The `\␣` (`␣` represents a space) forces TeX to insert a space after the command. If you don't want the space, like in `\emp,` you don't need the `\␣`, just write `\emp,`. If you do `\emp\,` you are doing a thin-space command `\,`. The `\emp{}` version can be used anywhere: `\emp{}␣is nice. \emp{}, is nice`, however the `\␣` version is used only where you need the space: `\emp\␣is nice. \emp, is nice`

Comment: Got it, thanks. I misread your \emp{} as \emph{} so that was the comments about emphasis. Sorry for that. Many thanks for the help.

Comment: No problem. Glad it helped :-)